# Sidebar not appearing in footer, but it appears everywhere else!

Tags: php, functions, sidebar, footer, register-sidebar

**Problem**
My sidebar is not displaying in the Wordpress footer.php file.

**functions.php**

```
<?php
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'social_media_sidebar' );
function social_media_sidebar() {
  register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Social Media Sidebar Widgets',
        'id'            => 'social_media_sidebar_widgets',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<span style="display:none;">',
        'after_title'   => '</span>',
  ));
}
?>
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'social_media_sidebar_widgets' ); ?>
</div>
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'social_media_sidebar_widgets' ); ?>
```

Note - the above footer.php call is not in a loop. That's the only thing I can think of that may be causing the widget to not display? I'm using the same call to get_sidebar in 3 other template files (within the loop) and they load just fine. I just can't get it to display in the footer. Nothing is being hidden with CSS.

**What can I do to get the social_media_sidebar_widgets sidebar to display in my footer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration in your footer tells WordPress to find the `sidebar-social_media_sidebar_widgets.php` file and apply it there.

I think what you want is to declare:

`<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'social_media_sidebar_widgets' ); ?>`

in your `footer.php` file.

Comment: a ha! that did the trick. Thank you, @Ryan! (will accept this answer once the time restriction passes)

Comment: All good, my friend! Glad I could be of help :-)